# Connecting with SQL Server Name and Port

Tags: sql-server, port, replication, ip-address

I am trying to configure Snapshot Replication using SQL Server Authentication. I can not use SQL Server Name in following format:

SQL Server IP address, Port Number.

Instead I have to provide SQL Server Name, not IP Address to configure replication. But when I am using this SQL Server Name, Port Number format, its giving me following error:

"Can not find server "Server Name""

What can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you say that you can't use the server's IP or name? If you get such an error it's because you used the *wrong* IP or name. The *name* when using TCP is the DNS name anyway. You'll have to explain what you did if you want people to help

Comment: BTW this isn't related to programming. This should be posted to `dba.stackexchange.com` but people there will say the same

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim cnn As SqlConnection

 cnn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=152.252.11.252;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sdds;Pwd=dsjdhshd;Max Pool Size=500;")
```

You can call like this also

Comment: Its pure SQL Server thing. I want to connect using SSMS and SQL Authentication to a server with name: IP Address, Port Number
But in case when we configure replication, then we need to provide Server Name, IP address does not work.

Comment: @MuraliDharDarshan it does. You'll have to explain what you did, what the error was and why you posted *here* if this isn't related to programming.